# Add tags to pages

Tags: tags, wordpress

I found a lots of plugins about this, most of them doesn't work, or the tag widget on page doesn't appear, only of categories.

My question is simple: how can I add tags to pages? I don't trust plugins anymore, so can I use a piece of code in my `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's nothing wrong on using plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php), as long as you trust the [source code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type).

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Add tags to pages
 */

add_action( 'init', 'tag_pages_so_23634122' );

function tag_pages_so_23634122() 
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code! well i see under pages, in the left part, Tags, but i don't see widget in right part where to choose tags. it must to be there or how it works?

Comment: I don't understand "widget"... the meta box appears on the right side.. can you post a screenshot?

Comment: yeah, that metabox in right side, it doesn't appear

Comment: Cool! I've seen that your previous questions also were solved and looks like you don't know [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: you are right, i didn't know how it works. thank you for this also :D